# Cakephp 2.4 Check Auth LoggedIn in every page?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I find out it is redundant for putting the below code in every single function just to check if user is logged in. Not sure if there is a better way to put the below code at else where that I can use it without pasting the same code again?

```
$this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried AppControllers beforeRender() method?
There you can put it for every action - once.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::beforeRender

Comment: Exactly what I do myself.

Comment: I don't. I use [convenience wrapper access](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Auth.php) as a variable free approach.